# Reporting keyword occurrence every minutes using Grep in Powershell

Tags: powershell, grep, export-to-csv

I need to report keyword occurrence using grep with power-shell and export the result in csv format if possible.

I need command similar to this one (it doesn't work for me in powershell)

```
cat .\PlaySound.txt | grep "Keyword" | grep $(date --date="@$(($(date +%s) - 3600))" "+%d/%b/%Y:%H") | wc -l
```

For exemple:

- 17:20 SomeKeyword : 13
- 17:21 SomeKeyword : 23
- 17:22 SomeKeyword : 18
- 17:23 SomeKeyword : 11
- ...
- 18:20 SomeKeyword : 10

Comment: 1) Please use code formatting in your question (4 space indent). 2) You're going to need to "translate" the above to its intended meaning/action (you're presuming that respondents will be able to decipher its meaning, and that may be an unwarranted assumption).

Comment: Thank you for your comment, my question is simple, i need to query a log file for some key words and count how much occurence i have each minutes (based on log timestamp) and then export the result in console output, txt file or in csv format using grep and power-shel. i hope it's clear now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the main issue is generating and formatting the timestamp?

In PowerShell, the equivalent would be:

```
Get-Date (Get-Date).AddHours(-1) -UFormat "+%d/%b/%Y:%H"
```

So to recreate the whole pipeline we can do something like this:

```
$timestamp = Get-Date (Get-Date).AddHours(-1) -UFormat "+%d/%b/%Y:%H"
Get-Content .\PlaySound.txt |Where-Object {$_ -match 'Keyword' -and $_ -match $timestamp} |Measure-Object -Line |Select-Object -Expand Lines
```

Comment: Can I use this $timestamp = Get-Date (Get-Date) -UFormat "+%yyyy-%MM-%dd %HH:%mm" ? for the following timestamp format 2020-08-14 15:05:25,767 ? I think i missed something here.

Comment: @MselmiAli Not sure I understand? You want it only to match keywords that were logged _exactly_ 1 hour ago, down to a milliseconds accuracy?

Comment: I have updated my quesion by adding a exemple of desired report